# What testing framework do you suggest for .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, .net-3.5

I'm vb.net programmer. I would like to start writing unit & user interface test for my web application. I would like to hear what frameworks do you suggest for writing those tests?

My requirement is that I have to be able to use this software together with Team Foundation Build Server and would be perfect if the vendor of a framework is Microsoft.

Please advice me something and write couple words why chosen by you technology is the best in your opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 and higher (non-Express editions), as well as Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite, include unit testing features.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest:

- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/?p=download) for testing
- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list) for mocking
- [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for running tests within the Visual Studio

Comment: I'm all for NUnit, but does it integrate with Team Foundation Build Server? And does it have anything to support UI testing of a web app?

Comment: It can integrate with anything as long as you add running NUnit tests  to the build process. Also look here http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 Although I'm using Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 0):

I am against unit testing because it is not proof you have no bugs. If tests fail, you have bugs. If tests succeed, maybe you have bugs maybe you don't. Integration tests done manually are good, but coded unit tests are waste of time. Unit tests are from extreme programming which was designed to slow developers down while the promoters of extreme programming do good job and get good reputation.

Comment: Ouch! I guess you get some harsh working experience :(

Comment: I am against compiling because it is not proof you have no bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[**MbUnit**](http://gallio.org) provides rich testing features with a high level of automation and built-in integration with many 3rd party tools (R#, PoSh, VS, MSBuild, CCNet, etc.)

[image]

It is part of the [**Gallio**](http://gallio.org) test automation platform, which also supports [NUnit](http://nunit.org/), MSTest, [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) and some other less known frameworks. Gallio provides several test runners (GUI, command-like, PoSh-snapin, R# plugin, etc.) and common reporting formats (Html, Xml, etc.)

[image]

*Bias: I'm an active contributor of the [Gallio OSS project](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/).*